# Time pressure and learning

Tags: learning

What are the effects of time pressure (salient vs. non-salient) and learning? Salient time pressure is basically when you have a countdown timer in front of you. Non salient time pressure would be when you have a timer going off after some preordained times (making a beep). Would the salient time pressure induce a person to do something more efficiently? Or would it be a distraction?

Sophie Leroy has [shown](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749597809000399) that switching tasks incurs a cost. In particular, there is attentional residue from the previous task. Time pressure, she shows, may help with this. It provides closure to a task. But what are the effects of time pressure on learning? I guess testing is a type of time pressure activity that is one of the best ways to learn.

**References**

W Leroy, S. (2009). Why is it so hard to do my work? The challenge of attention residue when switching between work tasks. Organizational Behavior and Human Decision Processes. Vol. 109. pp 168-181.

Comment: Just some personal observations to trigger some ideas: The effect is clearly task specific. When I "feel" I can finish the task or achieve some meaningful result in the specified time (e.g. when I do the d2-Test or get as many dollar bills as I can shovel into my pockets in 5 seconds), the time limit serves as motivator. When I "feel" I cannot achieve a useful result in the allotted time, the time limit is a stressor (e.g. when I have 5 seconds to run 100 meters, I simply won't run at all, because I know I cannot make it).

Comment: @what: Basically this is the Yerkes Dodson Law.

Answer (score 3):

This is a wide open question - I'm not sure that you can say there is an "effect on learning" due to time pressure. It's going to depend on a lot of factors, including the learning context, the learner, the amount of time they have to complete the task, etc.  Ultimately, all learning is time-limited, so you need to break this down into different lengths of time.

There are several theories that may speak about it. One is cognitive load theory (Paas & Van Merriënboer, 1994).  This theory is based on the limitations of working memory, where the "processing" of learning takes place.  Basically, there is `intrinsic load` required to learn a certain type of material, and this is a characteristic of the material to be learned.  There is also `extraneous load` during learning, which occurs when the learner must divert attention to tasks not directly relevant to the learning task (e.g. checking a clock, computing how much time is left, etc).

Based on CLT, one would expect a decrease in performance from having a clock sitting in front of the learner.  But again, I suspect that the amount of time vs. the time required will be a strong mediating factor.

**Edit**

I just skimmed the article you cited.  It seems like there are a lot more relevant sources there you could track down.  Why don't you do that and come back with what you find?

#### References

- Paas, F. G., & Van Merriënboer, J. J. (1994). Instructional control of cognitive load in the training of complex cognitive tasks. Educational Psychology Review,6(4), 351-371